# Stepping through a foreach loop - adding +1 to the end of it so next time it loops it starts on item 2

Tags: loop, pages

I'm creating a custom Google map that plots multiple markers.

### ***View the link as it will make it easier to explain what is happening and what I want***

If you click on each marker it shows company names that are grabbed from the child pages. At the moment it's showing ALL the company names on each marker. How can I show just one company name per marker?

Here's the code controlling the little popup:

```
$pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 1873, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order')); 
$counter = 1;
foreach($pages as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post); 
    $fields = get_fields();
    ?> 
    <p><?php $counter++; echo $fields->company_name;?></p>
    <?php
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Once it's looped through once, the next time it loops through I need it to start on the next child and not show the first one.

Comment: Please consider re-working your Q. What's a _dot_, _info per one "plotted" dot_, etc.?

Comment: @kaiser Just edited it now.

Comment: Hey Rob. Still don't know what's a _dot_... writing bold doesn't change too much...

Comment: @kaiser I've posted a link in the question that will explain it all.

Comment: This is a general PHP question, not a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `offset` argument, and only get 1 result:

```
global $my_page_offset;

if(!isset($my_page_offset))
  $my_page_offset = 0;

$pages = get_pages(array(
  'child_of'    => $post->ID, 
  'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
  'offset'      => $my_page_offset, 
  'number'      => 1,
));

$my_page_offset++;

...
```

I'm assuming here that you don't have much control over these loops, because you're doing them multiple times. This is why the global variable...

---

**Last try:**

After `var infowindow;` add this:

```
<?php

$pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
$data = array();
foreach($pages as $post){
  setup_postdata($post);
  $fields = get_fields(); 
  $data[] = '<p>'.$fields->company_name.'</p>';
}
wp_reset_query();

// the js array
echo 'var marker_data = ["'.implode('","', $data).'"];';
?>
```

Now infowindow.setContent should be:

```
infowindow.setContent(marker_data[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. It doesn't seem to echo out anything now.

Comment: Changing the offset to 1 made the first child page appear on all items.

Comment: what happens if you remove the `number` argument ?

Comment: Removing it makes it show everything again. It's almost as if I need to add a +1 inside the end of the foreach loop maybe?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question. That function is part of Google Maps :) You should post the entire javascript code, so we can see how are your markers created.

Comment: Not for this it isn't as I'm looping over WP data which is completely separate to the Google Maps stuff. It's impossible to control what WP data is looping through via Google Maps. It's almost at the point where we should all just ignore the Google stuff and just focus on looping through a WP foreach loop that iterates on each loop.

Comment: I forgot to increase the offset in the code above :) Try now

Comment: Thanks for all the attempts. This is what's currently happening: if I leave 'number' at 1 then the popup on the marker doesn't work, if I changed it to 2 then it shows the first child page on both the markers. See http://www.mediwales.com/mapping for progress.

Comment: The problem is that the gmaps adds the field that's generated with PHP trough a loop, and applies it to all elements. Post the entire code, especially the one around `places.push(new google...` (I guess you have another PHP foreach loop there?). You'll need to create a javascript array with fields for each element, and pass that to infowindow.setContent

Comment: Just edited the question with the whole code.

Comment: With the places.push(new google... I've hard coded them in, these will be foreach loops eventually though.

Comment: Thanks for trying again. The map doesn't load now.

Comment: @Rob Nice to see you finally posted the code, I've been asking you to do that all day on the SO question.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Sorry, been get caught up in several questions across several sites!

Comment: @OneTrickPony I've updated the question a bit. Looking around although it didn't work I think your onto something with the offset parameter. I think it needs an if statement somewhere though.

Comment: No it's not that. I've noticed an error in my previous code around the js array, try again with the updated version.

Comment: @OneTrickPony Thanks for another attempt. I tried it and the popup wasn't working at first so changed the line infowindow.setContent(marker_data[i]); to infowindow.setContent(marker_data[0]); and the info was appearing. So it seems the javascript just isn't looping through, not sure how to fix it though. Would it be that i is maybe clashing with other code?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that the php within the JS needed to be json encoded:

```
echo 'var marker_data = ' . json_encode($data) . ';';
```

Comment: ...which (again) demonstrates that this question didn't have anything directly to do with WordPress.